# Instantiate class with NSCODER

Tags: swift, initialization, instantiation, nscoder

I face a problem when trying to instantiate a class(SettingsView) that uses NSCoder, in another class(Swipe). The SettingsView class is already an instance of an objective -C class(FXBlurView)

I get the following error **"Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call"**. I realized that I have to call some parameters, but I do not know which.

SettingsView :

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Swipe :

```
var settings = SettingsView()//error occurs here
```

i already tried to use

```
init () {
   super.init (tint: ...)
  }
```

But it seems to be not functionnal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , i succeed to do it just by adding :

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    var settings = SettingsView(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

into my "Swipe" view controller.